# Making a long-term forecast with multiple linear regression and lagged variables in R

Tags: r, regression, forecast

Hello I am interested in making an hourly electric load forecast for more than 7 months ahead. My data set includes about 5 and a half years of hourly load  and temperature data. The model I am trying to implement is a multiple linear regression that includes temperature as an independent variable and month, weekday and hour as classification variables, as well as 24 variables of load lags; lag1 is the value of the electric load in the previous hour, lag2 is the value of energy load 2 hours before the current value and so on.

```
my_df <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/Load/main/my_df.csv", sep=";")

    
library(Hmisc)
mod_lm <- lm(LOAD ~ TEMPERATURE + MONTH + WEEKDAY + HOUR + Lag(LOAD,1) + Lag(LOAD, 2) + Lag(LOAD, 3) + Lag(LOAD, 4) + Lag(LOAD,5)+
               Lag(LOAD, 6) + Lag(LOAD, 7) + Lag(LOAD, 8) + Lag(LOAD,9) + Lag(LOAD, 10) + Lag(LOAD,11)+ Lag(LOAD, 12)+
               Lag(LOAD, 13)+ Lag(LOAD, 14) + Lag(LOAD, 15) + Lag(LOAD, 16) + Lag(LOAD, 17) + Lag(LOAD, 18)+
               Lag(LOAD, 19) + Lag(LOAD,20) + Lag(LOAD, 21) + Lag(LOAD, 22) +Lag(LOAD, 23)+ 
               Lag(LOAD,24), data=my_df)

summary(mod_lm)
```

The model looks like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dyn(LOAD ~ TEMPERATURE + MONTH + WEEKDAY + HOUR + 
    lag(LOAD, 1) + lag(LOAD, 2) + lag(LOAD, 3) + lag(LOAD, 4) + 
    lag(LOAD, 5) + lag(LOAD, 6) + lag(LOAD, 7) + lag(LOAD, 8) + 
    lag(LOAD, 9) + lag(LOAD, 10) + lag(LOAD, 11) + lag(LOAD, 
    12) + lag(LOAD, 13) + lag(LOAD, 14) + lag(LOAD, 15) + lag(LOAD, 
    16) + lag(LOAD, 17) + lag(LOAD, 18) + lag(LOAD, 19) + lag(LOAD, 
    20) + lag(LOAD, 21) + lag(LOAD, 22) + lag(LOAD, 23) + lag(LOAD, 
    24)), data = my_df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1155.48   -76.38    -3.80    72.12  1540.34 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    96.297801   5.399303  17.835  < 2e-16 ***
TEMPERATURE     0.147311   0.087598   1.682 0.092638 .  
MONTH          -0.013815   0.186592  -0.074 0.940980    
WEEKDAY       -20.396726   0.361845 -56.369  < 2e-16 ***
HOUR            1.290159   0.171243   7.534 5.01e-14 ***
lag(LOAD, 1)    1.375390   0.004447 309.307  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 2)   -0.666860   0.007378 -90.379  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 3)    0.205219   0.007890  26.010  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 4)   -0.176901   0.007905 -22.377  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 5)    0.128568   0.007932  16.208  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 6)   -0.028096   0.007960  -3.530 0.000417 ***
lag(LOAD, 7)   -0.058609   0.007950  -7.372 1.71e-13 ***
lag(LOAD, 8)    0.164145   0.007905  20.765  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 9)   -0.225412   0.007868 -28.650  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 10)   0.133046   0.007940  16.757  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 11)   0.014815   0.007948   1.864 0.062318 .  
lag(LOAD, 12)  -0.035893   0.007951  -4.515 6.36e-06 ***
lag(LOAD, 13)   0.025532   0.007956   3.209 0.001332 ** 
lag(LOAD, 14)  -0.028748   0.007962  -3.611 0.000306 ***
lag(LOAD, 15)  -0.095531   0.007928 -12.050  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 16)   0.227563   0.007876  28.894  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 17)  -0.189406   0.007912 -23.939  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 18)   0.070704   0.007947   8.897  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 19)   0.020112   0.007954   2.528 0.011462 *  
lag(LOAD, 20)  -0.103368   0.007936 -13.025  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 21)   0.181176   0.007901  22.931  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 22)  -0.204949   0.007907 -25.919  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 23)   0.533351   0.007334  72.723  < 2e-16 ***
lag(LOAD, 24)  -0.271700   0.004480 -60.654  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 131.8 on 46795 degrees of freedom
  (24 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9871,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9871 
F-statistic: 1.28e+05 on 28 and 46795 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

How do I form my `predict` function so that it produces a forecast that has the length of my forecasted temperature table (5736 values) and takes into account "forecasted" lagged load variables? I have been having difficulties using the dyn package , for some reason the lagged variables produce zero estimates.

```
forecast_df <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/Load/main/forecast_df.csv", sep=";")
```

This clearly won't work:

```
pred <-predict(mod_lm, newdata = forecast_df)
```

Thank you in advance, any idea on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: (1) dyn works with time series objects such as ts or zoo, not data frames.  (2) Be sure that dplyr is not loaded since it clobbers lag.  (3) lag with a positive lag uses the future.  You want negative lags here.  (4) the lags can be abbreviated as shown in the next point. (5) Try `dyn$lm(LOAD ~ TEMPERATURE + MONTH + WEEKDAY + HOUR + lag(LOAD, -(1:24)), zoo(Final_df))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for your comment! I get the following error when I run your code: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(29063L, 20185L, 14021L,  : 
  replacement has 1123776 rows, data has 46824

Comment: Have moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my_df from the question convert it to zoo and then run dyn$lm.  The original problem was that there was a datetime field that was character so zoo(my_df) converted it to a character object. If we use read.zoo and use it to convert the datetime field to POSIXct and tell it that that column is the index -- read.zoo assumes that the first column is the index unless specified otherwise -- then it works.  Also note that there are date times in the data that conflict with daylight savings time so the time zone must be specified as UTC.

Next follow the code at the end of `?dyn` to get predictions.  Since this can be very slow with large amounts of data we have just shown 3 predictions below.

As per my comment be sure that dplyr is not loaded since it clobbers lag.

```
library(dyn)
    
z <- read.zoo(my_df, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
fo <- LOAD ~ TEMPERATURE + MONTH + WEEKDAY + HOUR + lag(LOAD, -(1:24))
fm <- dyn$lm(fo, z)

fc.orig <- read.zoo(forecast_df, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")

# fc <- fc.orig
fc <- head(fc.orig, 3)

LOAD0 <- zoo(cbind(LOAD = 0), time(fc))
both <- rbind(z, cbind(LOAD0, fc))

for(i in seq(nrow(z) + 1, nrow(both))) {
   fit <- dyn$lm(fo, both, subset = seq_len(i-1))
   both[i, "LOAD"] <- tail(predict(fit, both[1:i, ]), 1)
}

# extract the forecast rows    
fc_new <- both[seq(nrow(z) + 1, nrow(both)), ]
```

### Note

```
my_df <- read.csv(file = 
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/Load/main/my_df.csv", sep=";")
forecast_df <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/Load/main/forecast_df.csv", sep=";")
```

Comment: Thank you, the model runs properly now. I still have a problem with my predict function though. I have forecasted values of temperatures that I use as newdata, but the function searches for the variable LOAD. How do I make the function take into account future lagged LOAD values?

Comment: When I run `pred <-predict(mod_lm, newdata = forecast_df)
`, I get the following message: `Error in lag(LOAD, -(1:24)) : object 'LOAD' not found` .

Comment: I have included it in my question. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/Load/main/forecast_df.csv

Comment: My question is how to include the new lagged LOAD values in my newdata.

Comment: I have seen it and unfortunately I do not understand it, that is why I posted this question.

Comment: Thank you for your code.  When I run `for(i in seq(nrow(z) + 1, nrow(both))) {
   fit <- dyn$lm(fo, both, subset = seq_len(i-1))
   both[i, "LOAD"] <- tail(predict(fit, both[1:i, ]), 1)
}` I get the following error: `Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- value : 
  'tsp' attribute must be numeric of length three
In addition: Warning message:
In if (k != round(k)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. As a result, the forecasted LOAD (`fc_new`) is zero

Comment: The error message is referring to ts objects but there are no ts objects in the code in the answer. Start a fresh instance of R and paste in the code in the Note at the end of the answer and then paste in the code from the body of the answer.  Be sure that no other packages are loaded.

Comment: You are right, when I copied your code in a clear script it worked. Thank you very much for your help!! !

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to load your data, but I think you'd need to run the regression inside a loop - at the end of each loop the new forecast gets recoded to `lag1`, the old `lag1` becomes `lag2` etc... at the loop runs from the first time (presumably now?) through all 5736 values.

You could store the results in a long table, with time as one column and forecast in the other column. Then at the end (or start) of each loop spread the most recent 24 values into new columns to be used as predictors. Add on your other predictors (temperature etc.) then run `predict` again, add the new prediction to your long table... Repeat until done.